# client/server interaction

Tags: c, visual-c++, client-server

When my program from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8876702/10396)  is responding to the client, it should send an encrypted message.
When the client connects it sends a message like "YourMessage."  Now I want to make it so that when the client connects this message should somehow be coded and something else appears on the client's screen.  How do I go about it?

Server code:

```
#include "wind.h"

using namespace std;

//begi
void main()
{

    long answer ;
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVERSION;
    DLLVERSION = MAKEWORD(2,1);

    answer = WSAStartup(DLLVERSION, &wsaData);

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int addrlen = sizeof(addr);

 SOCKET slisten;
 SOCKET  sConnect;

 sConnect = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);

 addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
 addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

 addr.sin_port = htons(1234);

 slisten = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);

 bind(slisten, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
 // unlimited clients
 listen(slisten, SOMAXCONN);

 //conditions
 for(;;)



      {
cout <<"waiting for client" <<endl;
if (sConnect = accept(slisten,(SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen))
      {
          cout<<" A connection was found" <<endl;

           answer = send(sConnect,       "YourMessage", 12 ,NULL);
         char cMyCharacter = 'A';
       int iMyAsciiValue = static_cast<int>(cMyCharacter);
      }

 }
}
```

Client code:

```
#include "clnt.h"

using namespace std;

void main ()
{
 string confirm;
 char message[200];
  string strmessage;

long answer;
WSAData wsaData;
WORD DLLVersion;
DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
answer = WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData);



SOCKADDR_IN addr;
 int addrlen = sizeof(addr);

  SOCKET sconnect;

  sconnect = socket(AF_INET,      SOCK_STREAM,NULL);

  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

  addr.sin_port = htons(1234);


cout <<" Do you want to connect to your server?[Y/N]" <<endl;
cin>> confirm;
if(confirm == "N")
{
      exit(1);
    }
       else
    {
        if(confirm == "Y")
        {
           connect(sconnect,     (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
          answer = recv(sconnect, message, sizeof(message), NULL);
          strmessage = message;
          cout << strmessage <<endl;
          getchar();
        }

     }

getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work just like it does now, but instead of sending the clear-text string you send the encrypted string. If the encryption makes a binary data-blob just send that as well, but then the client has to decrypt if before showing it to the user.